# WCF Exception returns empty Jquery error in Google Chrome browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, exception

WCF Exception returns empty Jquery error in Google Chrome browser

I have a wcf that sends the password. I have tried forcing an error, but the Chrome browser for the $ returns empty. The jquery ajax error.

wcfUser.svc:

> [OperationContract (), WebInvoke (Method = "POST", RequestFormat = 
>   WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat WebMessageFormat.Json =)]
>
> ```
>       public string lembrarSenha ()
>       {
>
>
>           try
>
>           {
>
>               int id = Convert.ToInt32 ("asssaas");
>               return id.ToString();
>
>           }
>           catch (Exception ex)
>           {
>
>
>               HttpContext.Current.Response.Write (ex.Message);
>               HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
>               HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush ();
>               return ex.Message;
>
>
>           }
>
>
>       }
> ```

jquery:

> $. ajax ({
>
> ```
>                   url: "wcf/wcfUser.svc/lembrarSenha",
>                   type: "POST",
>                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>                   dataType: 'json',
>                   ProcessData: true,
>                   success: function (msg) {
>
>                       if (msg.d == true) {
>                           alert ("Please check your inbox for your email.");
>
>                       Else {}
>                           alert ("Email is not registered in the system.");
>                       }
>
>                   }
>                   error: function (XHR, ErrorText, thrownError) {
>
>                       alert (xhr.responseText);
>
>                   }
>
>               });
> ```

Would have to return an error, but in Chrome returns empty, in other browsers returns the error correctly.